# How to use SetTimeout correctly (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, settimeout

I am working on an ionic-cordova app that uses `Geolocation`.

According to the app flow it is necessary to get an accurate position.

I wrote dedicated methods to achieve the location and I used `setTimeout` in them.

According to my logs it seems that I didn't use `setTimeout` correctly - or even worst I chose poorly and `setTimeout` is not what I need here.

This is my code:

```
  getFixedLocation() {
    let coordinates: Coordinates;
    let maxTries = 15;
    let isFixedLocation = false;

    this.forceFixLocation(10);

    do {
      console.log("Getting location, try #" + maxTries)
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS)
      .then((position) => {
        coordinates = position.coords;
      });

      if (coordinates.accuracy < 25 && coordinates.speed < 1) {
        isFixedLocation = true;
      } else {
        maxTries -= 1;
      }
    } while(maxTries > 0 && !isFixedLocation);

    if (isFixedLocation) {
      return coordinates;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  forceFixLocation(counter: number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(counter > 0) {
        console.log("Forcing location #" + counter)        
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS)
        .then((position) => {
          console.log("Got position, accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy)
        }); 
        this.forceFixLocation(counter - 1);
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
```

A look on the log reveals that my `do-while` loop is executed before the first iteration of `forceFixLocation`:

```
08-15 00:58:51.831 D/SystemWebChromeClient(19622): file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 56358 : Getting location, try #15
08-15 00:58:51.831 I/chromium(19622): [INFO:CONSOLE(56358)] "Getting location, try #15", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (56358)
08-15 00:58:51.831 D/GeolocationPlugin(19622): We are entering execute
08-15 00:58:51.841 D/SystemWebChromeClient(19622): file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1362 : ERROR
08-15 00:58:51.841 I/chromium(19622): [INFO:CONSOLE(1362)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1362)
08-15 00:58:54.834 D/SystemWebChromeClient(19622): file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 56381 : Forcing location #10
08-15 00:58:54.844 I/chromium(19622): [INFO:CONSOLE(56381)] "Forcing location #10", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (56381)
08-15 00:58:54.844 D/GeolocationPlugin(19622): We are entering execute
08-15 00:58:56.936 D/SystemWebChromeClient(19622): file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1362 : ERROR
08-15 00:58:56.946 I/chromium(19622): [INFO:CONSOLE(1362)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1362)
08-15 00:58:57.847 D/SystemWebChromeClient(19622): file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 56381 : Forcing location #9
08-15 00:58:57.847 I/chromium(19622): [INFO:CONSOLE(56381)] "Forcing location #9", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (56381)
```

What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function inside `forceFixLocation` will be called first time after 3 sec. When you calling `this.forceFixLocation(10);` from `getFixedLocation` - it immediate continues to next line and doing the logic of while. 
More than that, `getFixedLocation` may already return some value, but you will still get `forceFixLocation` called every 3 second (10 times).

Comment: I understand what happens with the current code. The question is how to modify it so the do-while logic will be executed only after all ten calls to `forceFixLocation` returns.

Comment: extract do - while logic into separate function and call it from forceFixLocation.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a fundamental information here. And it's the **JavaScript event loop!**

You can NOT use `do while` because it will **never** (ever) end, and will hang your application, as the logs indicate.

It also looks like you are not waiting for the promise to resolve.. the `then` method a promise provides is just a function that might/will happen in the future. Your `do/while` hangs the app so it can't resolve to this promise...

I would suggest trying async/await as it offers a similar syntax to what you are expecting to get out of JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with that? I read about async/await but I am not sure how to modify the `do while` logic to async/await.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the logic that you are trying to achieve... I'll best to open a new question on how to convert a code to async/await